# Unexpected error while eof parsing

Tags: python, parsing, eof

My code doesn't work and I cant fix it please help. it the last line of code

sorry I don't know how to put it in one of those boxes (I'm very new to coding and python)

```
def start():
    print ("Type start.")
    prompt_sta()
    print

def prompt_sta ():
    prompt_0 = raw_input ("Enter command:    ")
    try:
        if prompt_0 == "start":
            outside_house ()
        elif prompt_0 == "begin":
            print ("Know when to follow instructions...")
            print
            prompt_sta ()
        elif prompt_0 == "help":
            print ("""Commands: help start begin""")
            prompt_sta ()
        else:
            print ("You must enter a valid command.")
            print
            prompt_sta ()
    except ValueError:
        "Type start."
        print
        print (prompt_sta ())

def outside_house ():
    print ("You are outside a small house.")

def prompt_outside ():
    prompt_1 = raw_input ("Enter Command:    ")
    try:
        if prompt_0 == "enter":
            inside_house ()
        elif prompt_0 == "help":
            print ("""Commands:    enter    help""")
            prompt_outside ()
        else:
            print ("Type a valid command.")
            print
            prompt_outside ()
```

Comment: What do you expect your code to be doing?

Comment: Its just test game to learn the ropes it should be asking for an input, then if its a wrong input then print "Type a valid command"

Answer (score 1):

For every `try` you need an `except`:

```
def prompt_outside ():
    prompt_1 = raw_input ("Enter Command:    ")
    try:
        ...
    except:
        ...
```

The error comes from not having the `except` after the `try`. You can have something like this for example:

```
def prompt_outside ():
    prompt_1 = raw_input ("Enter Command:    ")
    try:
        if prompt_0 == "enter":
            inside_house ()
        elif prompt_0 == "help":
            print ("""Commands:    enter    help""")
            prompt_outside ()
        else:
            print ("Type a valid command.")
            print
            prompt_outside ()
    except:
        print 'exception'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, now I have a new problem though, instead of running the beginning it has nothing

Comment: @print'Words' That's simply because you defined functions but never ran them. Just write `start()` at the end of the file without indentation.

Comment: You probably don't want an empty except, as you don't want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`s or really anything that inherits from `BaseException` if you really want to catch everything, use `except Exception: `.

Comment: do i have to run all functions or just start at the end

Comment: @print'Words' That depends on what you want to do. It appears you want do run `start()` and reach other functions from their. You probally want do add `prompt_outside ()` after `print ("You are outside a small house.")`.

Comment: @Reticality That depends on what version of Python you have, as noted [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) any version above *2.4* you can just say `except:` other than `except  Exception`, as it will indeed catch all exceptions. Anyways getting in details here isn't really the point, I'm simply saying some exception needs to be added after `try`.